# Angular JS game - Creating and destroying sub-controllers with methods

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm creating an AngularJS and HTML5-based game that consists of users finding and clicking on birds. I want birds to appear at random places on the screen. If you click a bird - or if you wait more than 5 seconds - the bird automatically disappears.

I'm new to Angular, but I thought I would approach this problem by...

1. Creating a controller that is responsible for managing game
   sessions (time limit, difficulty, etc.)
2. Using that
   controller to create Bird objects (sub-controllers?) at a regular
   interval.
3. Putting logic into each of the Bird objects so
   that they automatically destroy themselves after 5 seconds or if
   they are clicked.

Here's the main controller that created for part 1 of my problem:

```
 myGameModule.controller( 'BirdActivityCtrl', function BirdActivityCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.difficulty = 'Easy';
    $scope.reward = 250; 

    $scope.spawn_interval = 1000;
    $scope.status = 'starting';

    $scope.birds_required = 30; 
    $scope.birds_clicked = 0; 
    $scope.time_left = 60; 

    $scope.start = function(){
     location = '#/birds_in_progress';
     $scope.status = 'in_progress';
   }
         $scope.cancel = function(){
    location = '#/cafeteria';
  }
});
```

Specifically, I am asking for help with Parts 2 and 3 of my question (mentioned above). I know that Angular has strict conventions for separating DOM elements from controllers.  What is the correct way to spawn bird objects (which will be tied to DIVs on the page) and to destroy them after 5 seconds? Thank you for reading. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DOM-related work should be in [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Any directive can have it's own controller, it will be your `BirdController`. For any new bird instance (`div` with directive) new controller and scope will be created.

I suggest you put all your birds in some data structire in a [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services) accessible from any part of your app with DI. Then you can simply use [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) for you birds!

Something like this pseudocode should work:

```
game.factory('BirdStorage', ['in', 'ject', 'ables', function(){
    var birds = [];

    return {
        addBird : function(){
            birds.push({...})
        },
        deleteBird : function(id){
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
}]);

game.directive('bird', ['in', 'ject', 'ables', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div>...</div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ...
        }
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            ...
        }
        link: function(){
            ...
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then you can use it in HTML like an element:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="bird in birds">
        <bird attrs=...>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`birds` will come from a service you defined earlier.

And a logic to remove bird will come to `BirdStorage`. Just create a timeout that will delete specified bird:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    this.deleteBird(id);
}, 5000)
```